# Java development server incorrectly throwing FeatureNotEnabled exception?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a java app engine web service that uses Google Cloud Storage accessed through the Cloud Storage JSON API library. After upgrading my SDK to 1.19.30, I started getting exceptions from a basic piece of code that gets a file out of GCS. The same code works fine on earlier SDKs (1.19.25 for example) and it also works fine when deployed to app engine. So.. I'm wondering if this bug in the development server.

For now, my workaround is to use an older SDK.

The exception is:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Files API is disabled. Further information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:515)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:484)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:461)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And the method that triggers it is:

```
 private void getFile(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FileEntity fe) {
  try {

     GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(fe.getBucketName(), fe.getObjectName());
     GcsFileMetadata metadata = GCS.getInstance().getMetadata(filename);
     resp.setContentType(metadata.getOptions().getMimeType());
     GcsInputChannel readChannel = GCS.getInstance().openPrefetchingReadChannel(filename, 0, GCS.BUFFER_SIZE);
     GCS.copy(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel), resp.getOutputStream());
  } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: How did you discern that the method posted is causing the exception? It doesn't appear in the stack trace...

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Thanks Nick.

I guess my call is not in the stack trace because the call to openPrefetchingReadChannel (via Google's library) is making a call (via the API) to whatever is emulating the cloud storage in the development server (presumably in another thread).

Comment: It seems like this is a genuine issue, and not a case of your own use of the outdated Files API. Likely a call within the Cloud Storage That being the case I think you should make a posting to [the Public Issue Tracker for the App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/entry).

Comment: We monitor certain Public Issue Trackers very closely and you should see a reply quickly, especially if you provide some minimal code required to observe the issue. The method you posted seems good, I think just some explanation of how it's called (what populates the args?) would help.

Comment: Nick, I managed to post an issue with the boilerplate text: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12622 Sorry about that.. it happened because I was switching Google identities and didn't notice the form got reset! I added comments to explain.

Comment: No worries, it looks like a good report! One of us will be in touch shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From testing on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12622), it looks like this is related to using an older version of appengine-gcs-client (pre 0.5) which uses the deprecated Files API. Updating the [libraries and dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/download) should do the trick.